# How to do ng-repeat with limitTo + condition in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I need to show a limited list with ng-repeat, applying a condition, but I can't get it.

I'm developing a filter with several categories and subcategories.

For each category, I need to show the first 5 categories that have 1 result minimum.

To do this, I've created a count() function that is called when the user clicks on any subcategory checkbox, and the function refreshes the values.

The code for the ng-repeat is:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-right" ng-repeat="(id, nombre) in subcategoria" ng-if="(filteredproductosMenos<?= ucfirst ( $categoria['abrev'] ) ?> | filter:search:strict | filter:count('<?= $categoria['campo'] ?>',id)).length">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="use<?= ucfirst ( $categoria['abrev'] ) ?>[id]" checked="" id="list-filters-sidebar-form-<?=$i?>-{{j}}" name="list-filters-<?=$i?>-{{j}}">
    <label for="list-filters-sidebar-form-<?=$i?>-{{j}}">{{nombre}} ({{ (filteredproductosMenos<?= ucfirst ( $categoria['abrev'] ) ?> | filter:search:strict | filter:count('<?= $categoria['campo'] ?>',id)).length }})</label>
</div>
```

This code shows the subcategories that have 1 result minimum, but if I add "limitTo:5" to the ng-repeat, only the first 2 subcategories are shown, because the first 3 subcategories doesn't have results.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward. Here are two solutions, one with Angular and one with Angular + angular-filter module.

***Solution 1, pure Angular, without added module :***

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | filter: hasResult | limitTo: 5">{{category.name}}</div>
```

**Explanation:**

We filter the items of the array that have results, then we apply the `limitTo` filter. The function `hasResult` is defined as follows :

```
$scope.hasResult = function (category) {
    return category.results.length > 0;   
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ds3yznvo/1/)**

---

***Solution 2, Angular with module [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#omit) :***

Almost the same solution as the previous, but here we are using the `omit` filter of angular-filter, instead of the built-in filter called `filter` :

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | omit: hasNoResult | limitTo: 5">{{category.name}}</div>
```

**Explanation:**

- `omit` : this filter comes from angular-filter module. We drop the categories that satisfies the function `hasNoResult`. The function is declared as follows :

  ```
  $scope.hasNoResult = function (category) {
      return category.results.length === 0;   
  }
  ```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ds3yznvo/)**

---

Note, for both solutions I assume the array of categories looks like that :

```
$scope.categories = [{
    name: 'cat 1',
    results: []
}, {
    name: 'cat 2',
    results: [0, 1]
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to apply an Angular function in the omit condition:

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-right" ng-repeat="(id, nombre) in subcategoria | omit:'(filteredproductosMenos<?= ucfirst ( $categoria['abrev'] ) ?> | filter:search:strict | filter:count(\'<?= $categoria['campo'] ?>\',id)).length == 0'">

I don't have the results initially, because the results depend on the filter, dinamicly.